# Rails 3.1 hash each gives TypeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, typeerror

I have hash(Hash.from_xml) which looks like this (from inspect):

```
{
"FileName"=>"hofplayers.xml",
"Version"=>"1.0",
"UserID"=>"3955847", 
"FetchedDate"=>"2011-08-16 00:41:02", 
"PlayerList"=>{
    "Player"=>{
        "PlayerId"=>"92121587", 
        "FirstName"=>"Gennady", 
        "NickName"=>nil, 
        "LastName"=>"Buzykin", 
        "Age"=>"45", 
        "NextBirthday"=>"2011-09-24 22:10:00", 
        "ArrivalDate"=>"2008-03-08 16:37:00", 
        "ExpertType"=>"15", 
        "HofDate"=>"2010-01-23 16:10:00", 
        "HofAge"=>"40"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I'm iterating with each as there can be more then one player:

```
<% @hof['PlayerList']['Player'].each do |player| %>
    <%= player['NickName']%>
<% end %>
```

And it fails with *TypeError: can't convert String into Integer*. But it works like I want when there is more than one player. The problem seems to be that when there is single player each makes arrays instead of hash, player.inspect gives:

```
 ["PlayerId", "92121587"]
 ["FirstName", "Gennady"]
 ["NickName", nil]
 ["LastName", "Buzykin"]
 ["Age", "45"]
 ["NextBirthday", "2011-09-24 22:10:00"]
 ["ArrivalDate", "2008-03-08 16:37:00"]
 ["ExpertType", "15"]
 ["HofDate", "2010-01-23 16:10:00"]
 ["HofAge", "40"]
```

Instead of

```
 {
     "PlayerId"=>"25787535", 
     "FirstName"=>"Rico", 
     "NickName"=>nil, 
     "LastName"=>"van Oostveen", 
     "Age"=>"42", 
     "NextBirthday"=>"2011-10-23 22:18:00", 
     "ArrivalDate"=>"2006-02-11 18:43:00", 
     "ExpertType"=>"2", 
     "HofDate"=>"2010-04-25 22:01:00", 
     "HofAge"=>"38"
 }
```

So what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does PlayerList become an array when there is more than one player? Or do you get PlayerList => {"Player1" => {...}, "Player2" => {...}}

Comment: @phillee It becomes an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `each` on a Hash, you get a list of key/value pairs, then you try to index those pairs with a string and that gives you your error. There's not much you can do to change what `from_xml` does but you can work around it.

You could patch the Hash in your controller:

```
if(@hof['PlayerList']['Player'].is_a?(Hash))
    @hof['PlayerList']['Player'] = [ @hof['PlayerList']['Player'] ]
end
# or
if(!@hof['PlayerList']['Player'].is_a?(Array))
    @hof['PlayerList']['Player'] = [ @hof['PlayerList']['Player'] ]
end
```

If you don't have what you're expecting, you'd just make it an array with one element; which test you choose depends on what sorts of things you're expecting to get from `from_xml` but I'd lean towards the "not array" check since that exactly matches what you're trying to do.

Or you could try sorting it out in your view:

```
<% [ @hof['PlayerList']['Player'] ].flatten(1).each do |player| %>
```

That basically wraps whatever you have in an array and then flattens it one level, the [`flatten(1)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000280) call is needed in case you already have an array. If you start off with an array then the `[ ].flatten(1)` is a no-op (the `flatten` call will undo what `[]` does) that won't have any noticeable effect other than a bit of wasted CPU time; if you start with a hash, then `[ ... ]` will turn it into an array and `flatten` won't do anything (but waste a bit of CPU).

Comment: Flatten seems to be working but I'll check tomorrow more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

one thing that comes to mind is that this:

```
<% @hof['PlayerList']['Player'].each do |player| %>
  <%= player['NickName']%>
<% end %>
```

does not loop through the players. It loops through the name/value pairs of the 'Player' hash. EDIT. By this I mean that it will loop through key1, value1, key2, value2, key3,...etc. One for each iteration of the loop...

I would think you'd want something like this:

```
<% @hof['PlayerList'].each_pair do |player, player_data| %>
  <%= player_data['NickName']%>
<% end %>
```